# How to retain an element's hover area?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create elements which will change position slightly when hovered - in this example we have a primitive attempt at a 3D button which is slightly depressed when hovered over. All works as intended, unless the top and left 3 pixels are hovered over, in which case it rapidly flickers between the two states.

Is it possible, without creating a duplicate transparent element, to make the hover area not shift with the element and eliminate this behaviour? JavaScript and JQuery solutions are okay but pure HTML/CSS would be best.

```css
#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 3px #aaa;
}

#button:hover {
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 2.1px #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/tn3e4q64/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a pseudo element `:after` and style this instead:

```css
#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#button:after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00f;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 3px #aaa;
  content: "";
}

#button:hover:after {
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 2.1px #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be just what I'm looking for, and what a speedy response too! The other answers are great as well but this is the only one (so far) to work perfectly under Chrome for me. Thank you so much! I really must learn to use :before and :after for things more often.

Comment: It works because only the `:after` gets translated, but the event is still tied to `#button`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative position and left/top offsets instead, that seems to work better (i.e. without flickering):

```css
#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 3px #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

#button:hover {
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 2.1px #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Still flickers on the top/left edges for me.

Comment: Good point. Only flickers on Chrome (Mac) for me. Not on Firefox or Safari.